# Getting a MappingException due to a ClassCastException while saving an object using Morphia-MongoDB

Tags: java, mongodb, morphia, mongo-java, mongo-java-driver

I have a Java class which has the following structure.

```
class Item{
...
@Embedded("zpl")
public List<ZplList> zplList = new ArrayList<ZplList>();
@Embedded("rohs")
public List<RohsList> rohsList = new ArrayList<RohsList>();
...
//Getters and setters
}
```

My ZplList class looks like this.

```
@Embedded
public class ZplList {
@Property("csass")
@org.javers.core.metamodel.annotation.Id
public String zpl;
@Property("csasd")
public Date startDate;
@Property("csaed")
public Date endDate;
@Override
public boolean equals(Object object) {
    ZplList obj = (ZplList) object;
    if (this.zpl==null ? obj.zpl!=null : !this.zpl.equals(obj.zpl)) {
        return false;
    }
    if (this.startDate==null ? obj.startDate!=null : 
    !this.startDate.equals(obj.startDate)) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    int hash = 3;
    hash = 7 * hash + this.zpl.hashCode();
    if(this.startDate!=null)
        hash = 7 * hash + this.startDate.hashCode();
    return hash;
}

}
```

My RohsList class looks similar to ZplList class.

```
@Embedded
public class RohsList {

@Property("rohs")
public String rohs;
@Property("rhssd")
public Date startDate;
@Property("rhsed")
public Date endDate;

@Override
public boolean equals(Object object) {
    RohsList obj = (RohsList) object;
    if (this.rohs==null ? obj.rohs!=null : !this.rohs.equals(obj.rohs)) {
        return false;
    }
    if (this.startDate==null ? obj.startDate!=null : 
    !this.startDate.equals(obj.startDate)) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    int hash = 3;
    if(this.rohs!=null)
    hash = 7 * hash + this.rohs.hashCode();
    if(this.startDate!=null)
        hash = 7 * hash + this.startDate.hashCode();
    return hash;
 }
}
```

When I try to save an Item object using Morphia, I am getting an exception as follows in the datastore.save() call. Is there any issue with my annotations? Please suggest a fix for this.

```
14:36:29,771 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-3) org.mongodb.morphia.mapping.MappingException: Error mapping field:com.mdm.ui.web.domain.Item.rohsList

14:36:29,773 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-3)    at org.mongodb.morphia.mapping.Mapper.toDBObject(Mapper.java:906)

14:36:29,774 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-3)    at org.mongodb.morphia.mapping.Mapper.toDBObject(Mapper.java:535)

14:36:29,774 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-3)    at org.mongodb.morphia.DatastoreImpl.entityToDBObj(DatastoreImpl.java:1322)

14:36:29,775 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-3)    at org.mongodb.morphia.DatastoreImpl.save(DatastoreImpl.java:1219)

14:36:29,775 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-3)    at org.mongodb.morphia.DatastoreImpl.save(DatastoreImpl.java:704)

14:36:29,776 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-3)    at org.mongodb.morphia.DatastoreImpl.save(DatastoreImpl.java:698)

14:36:29,777 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-3)    at com.mdm.ui.logic.dao.impl.SingleItemDaoImpl.submitItem(SingleItemDaoImpl.java:1532)

14:36:29,797 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-3) Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.mdm.ui.web.domain.ZplList cannot be cast to com.mdm.ui.web.domain.RohsList

14:36:29,797 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-3)    at com.mdm.ui.web.domain.RohsList.equals(RohsList.java:57)

14:36:29,798 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-3)    at java.util.HashMap.put(Unknown Source)

14:36:29,798 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-3)    at org.mongodb.morphia.mapping.Mapper.toDBObject(Mapper.java:910)

14:36:29,798 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-3)    at org.mongodb.morphia.mapping.Mapper.toDBObject(Mapper.java:535)

14:36:29,799 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-3)    at org.mongodb.morphia.mapping.EmbeddedMapper.writeCollection(EmbeddedMapper.java:235)

14:36:29,811 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-3)    at org.mongodb.morphia.mapping.EmbeddedMapper.toDBObject(EmbeddedMapper.java:88)

14:36:29,812 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-3)    at org.mongodb.morphia.mapping.Mapper.writeMappedField(Mapper.java:793)

14:36:29,813 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-3)    at org.mongodb.morphia.mapping.Mapper.toDBObject(Mapper.java:904)
```

Comment: Can you add the `RohsList` to the post ?

Comment: @Veeram Added the class.

Comment: Your classes and mapping looks good. Can you add rest of the code to reproduce this problem ?

Comment: @Veeram I am just populating this Item object and doing a datastore.save. It throws this exception. I verified that zplList and rohsList were not null and contains only corresponding objects.

Comment: Can you add exact data  that you are mapping and code before datastore.save ? You may have mixed object in each of the embedded objects. I can only help you better if you can add more code